# C++ Pointers Dilemma

Tags: c++

I have been playing with pointers in C++ for the last few hours.
Then I got stuck on this...

```
vector<int> one[3]; 
vector<int>* two[3]; 
vector<vector<int> > three(3);
vector<int>** four = new vector<int>*[3];
```

I would like to create an array(or a vector) that contains 3 vectors of integers.

What I think I know (correct me if I'm wrong):

- ONE is an array of three std::vector objects (all of them are being initialized using the default constructor, I guess)
- TWO is an array of three std::vector pointers. It means that I have to dynamically alloc the three pointers, like this:

  ```
  two[0] = new vector<int>();
  two[1] = new vector<int>();
  two[2] = new vector<int>();
  ```
- THREE is a vector that contains three std::vector initialized objects.
- FOUR is a pointer to the first of three std::vector pointers.

Which is the best way to achieve that (and why?)

**UPDATE:**

This is the the output of LLDB when I print those variables.
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=JLyeB4uK
It doesn't sound right...

Code is:

```
//METHOD ONE: 
vector<int> one[3];  
//METHOD TWO:
vector<int>* two[3]; 
two[0] = new vector<int>();
two[1] = new vector<int>();
two[2] = new vector<int>();
//METHOD THREE: 
vector<vector<int> > three(3);
//METHOD FOUR:
vector<int>** four = new vector<int>*[3]; 
four[0] = new vector<int>();
four[1] = new vector<int>();
four[2] = new vector<int>();
```

Thanks :)

Comment: `three` seems to accomplish exactly what you describe, and as a bonus is probably the most idiomatic. Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: I'm compiling the code with Clang and the lldb output is quite enigmatic. It doesn't sound right: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=JLyeB4uK.

Comment: The `size=0` may refer to the first vector within the `three` vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to create an array(or a vector) that contains 3 vectors of integers

```
std::array<std::vector<int>,3> myThreeVectors;
```

would be the best choice IMHO.
Unfortunately this isn't available for pre-[c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) standard. As a surrogate you could best use the simple [c](/questions/tagged/c)-style array (any decent [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) compiler should be able to handle the class instantiations of plain array elements correctly):

```
std::vector<int> myThreeVectors[3] = { };
```

which is equivalent to

```
std::vector<int> myThreeVectors[3] = 
                    { std::vector<int>()
                    , std::vector<int>()
                    , std::vector<int>()
                    };
```

Here's a [running](http://ideone.com/CDtQAu) sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std; // Don't use this in headers

std::vector<int> myThreeVectors[3] = { };

int main() {

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        cout << "myThreeVectors[" << i << "].size() = " << 
                myThreeVectors[i].size() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<int> myThreeVectors[3] = { std::vector<int>() };` This does not initialize every element to `std::vector<int>()`; it initializes the first to this, and value initializes the remaining two elements. Makes no difference in this case, but it is misleading.

Comment: @C.R. IIRC this syntax means to **initialize** any remaining items with this value. Can you show some proof of your statements?

Comment: "If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members or initializer clauses is completely empty, the remaining members are initialized by empty lists, which performs value-initialization. If a member of a reference type is one of these remaining members, the program is ill-formed (references cannot be value-initialized)" from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Comment: It is easy to verify the above statements; `int a[2] = {1}; std::cout << a[0] << ' ' << a[1] << std::endl;` The result is `1 0`.

Comment: @C.R. Yup, I think you're right. I was confused by some syntax I've seen valid for [tag:c++11] using an ellipsis (`...`), which deduces to initializer list?

Comment: I compiled my code using GCC-4.8 (instead of Clang) and it works fine. Clang sucks.

Answer (score 0):

What version of LLDB are you using?

With TOT, I get:

> (std::__1::vector > [3]) one = {
>
> [0] = size=0 {}
>
> [1] = size=0 {}
>
> [2] = size=0 {}
>
> }
>
> (std::__1::vector > *[3]) two = {
>
> [0] = 0x00000001001039a0 size=0
>
> [1] = 0x00000001001039c0 size=0
>
> [2] = 0x00000001001039e0 size=0
>
> }
>
> (std::_1::vector_1::vector >, 
>   std::__1::allocator > >
>   ) three = size=3 {
>
> [0] = size=0 {}
>
> [1] = size=0 {}
>
> [2] = size=0 {}
>
> }
>
> (std::__1::vector > **) four =
>   0x0000000100103980 size=0

Comment: I'm on OSX. Compiler is:                                           `Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix`

Comment: LLDB: `lldb-300.2.53`